# How to pass value from template HTML to component to then be used in service

Tags: angular5, angular6

I want to fetch id from component.html into component.ts to pass it to a service.

.ts file is;

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http/src/response';
import { SendUsingApiService } from '../send-using-api.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { setDefaultService } from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-org-info',
  templateUrl: './org-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./org-info.component.css'],
  providers: [SendUsingApiService]
})

export class OrgInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  orgData: string[] = [];
  Id = 1;

  editRecord:FormGroup;
  constructor(private httpService: HttpClient, private _serv: SendUsingApiService, 
    private fb: FormBuilder, private _ar:ActivatedRoute, private _r:Router) {
      this.editRecord = this.fb.group({
        Id:['1', []],
        OrganisationName:['', []],
        ContactPerson:['', []],
        ContactPersonHPNo:['', []],
        ContactPersonEmailId:['', []]

      });
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this._ar.snapshot.params.Id, "+ve");
    this._ar.params.subscribe(() => {
      this._serv.getUsers(this._ar.snapshot.params.Id).subscribe((res)=>{
        console.log(res);
        this.setUser(res);
      });
  });

}
```

I am getting the value for console.log(this._ar.snapshot.params.Id); as undefined "+ve".

I want to get the Id value in console.

As per requests I am adding html part, though little adjusted;

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
            <a class="btn btn-basic" [routerLink]="['/org-info',data['Id']]" role="button" (click)="getOrgData(data.Id)">View</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          </td>
```

Comment: I'm not working with angular and cannot help but maybe you should edit the title it's somekind of confusing (this is how I got here strange title)

Comment: I agree with dark_982 your title is a bit confusing, I have made an edit with title recommendation... I also recommend providing an example of your html as it will be needed to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined a property instead of Id = 1; (above)

```
paramId = '';
```

then, within ngOnInit;

```
ngOnInit() {
this.paramId = this._ar.snapshot.params.Id;
console.log(paramId, "+ve");                                                         
}
```

Doing this, I got the Id value instead of undefined.